# Image style not generated

Tags: 8

I'm runnig  drupal on nginx
my nginx config file is :

```
proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=1d;
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
        ssl_certificate_key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
        root /var/www/xxxxxxxxxxx/html;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name xxxxxxxxxxx.com www.xxxx.com;
        expires $expires;
    client_max_body_size 30M;
        keepalive_requests 100000;
        keepalive_timeout 65;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

     gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
 
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        # Specify the minimum length of the response to compress (default 20)
        gzip_min_length 500;

 location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Block access to scripts in site files directory
    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

    location @rewrite {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1; # For Drupal <= 6
        rewrite ^ /index.php; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|/(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config)$|/#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }


    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
    # the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
    # and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
    # This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
    # you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
    # laxer rule, such as:
    #   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
    # pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
    # release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        # Ensure the php file exists. Mitigates CVE-2019-11043
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
        # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
        # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        # PHP 5 socket location.
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        # PHP 7 socket location.
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

   location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
       proxy_cache my_zone;
       proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri$http_authorization";
       proxy_cache_valid 404, 302 1m;
       proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
       add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
    # with a language prefix.
    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Enforce clean URLs
    # Removes index.php from urls like www.example.com/index.php/my-page --> www.example.com/my-page
    # Could be done with 301 for permanent or other redirect codes.
    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/(.*)") {
        return 307 $1$2;
    }

}
```

when an image uploaded it's image style not generated.also when i check style folder that's not exist and not generated.
this is my permission folders :

```
sites -----> 755
default ---- > 775
files --- > 775
```

owner/group of my site file is **www-data www-data**

also I added two lines to **settings.php**:

```
$config['image.settings']['suppress_itok_output'] = TRUE;
$config['image.settings']['allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

even I used  **"drush image-flush"** and my image style flushed but styles not regenerated.

Answer (score 1):

The image derivative is created when it's requested, not when the image to which the image style is applied is uploaded.

When the URL for an image derivative is accessed, [`ImageStyleDownloadController::deliver()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Controller%21ImageStyleDownloadController.php/function/ImageStyleDownloadController%3A%3Adeliver/8.9.x) is invoked, and the image derivative is created, if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: this problem maked after changed web server , before this problem I called images with views block.
i call image field and show image with image style, but after change web server , drupal cant generate  image in image style folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. create sites/default/files/styles folder manually
2. set its permissions to 775
3. create .htaccess file with following content:

```
    <Files *>
      SetHandler none
    </Files>
```

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2015-06-16/image-styles-not-generating#comment-11859066)

Comment: this is by default htaccess :

`code`


Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>

`code`

 I substitute this with your answer but not worked